# Like methods for integer field in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

The following code for like statement throws an error can anyone help?

```
 var results = from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
               where SqlMethods.Like(c.Field<int>("Design_no").ToString(),
                                     "%" + Auto_txt_desi.Text.Tostring() + "%,")
                select c;
                DataView view = results.AsDataView();
                dt = view.ToTable();
```

Comment: Can you put your query in words for better understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`SqlMethods.Like`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like(v=VS.110).aspx) is a method for `Linq-To-Sql` to query a database not for [`Linq-To-DataSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977(v=vs.110).aspx) which is a subset of `Linq-To-Objects`. You can use pure .NET methods instead:

```
var rows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
           let Design_no = row.Field<int>("Design_no").ToString()
           where Design_no.Contains(Auto_txt_desi.Text)
           select row;
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The SQL Server `LIKE` functionality cannot be exposed through
>   translation of existing common language runtime (CLR) and .NET
>   Framework constructs, and is unsupported outside of a LINQ to SQL
>   context. The use of this method outside of LINQ to SQL **will always
>   throw an exception of type `NotSupportedException`**.

Comment: I think the design_no should contains Text & not the other way around.Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The SQL Server LIKE functionality is unsupported outside of a LINQ to SQL context. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like%28v=vs.110%29.aspx